# Get Original Field Name on GraphQL

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java, graphql-spqr, graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter

I'm using https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr with spring-boot java application. I can reach to alias name easily but how can I reach to original fieldName?

```
 class Food {
   @GraphQLQuery(name = "aliasNameX", description = "A food's name")
   private String originalName; 
   ...
 }

  ....

  @GraphQLQuery(name = "foods") // READ ALL
   @Override
   public List<Food> getFoods(@GraphQLEnvironment ResolutionEnvironment env) {
       DataFetchingFieldSelectionSet selectionSet = env.dataFetchingEnvironment.getSelectionSet();
       List<SelectedField> fields = selectionSet.getFields();
       for (SelectedField f: fields)
       {
           System.out.println(f.getName());
       }
       return foodRepository.findAll();
   }
```

When I run this code, Output looks like with alias fields: "aliasNameX", ..., but I need original name like "originalName". Is there a way to do it?

**Solved, according to:**

https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr/issues/381

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my original answer here as well.

You want the underlying field names, but from a level above. Still possible, but ugly :(

```
for (SelectedField selectedField : env.dataFetchingEnvironment.getSelectionSet().getImmediateFields()) {
    Optional<Operation> operation = Directives.getMappedOperation(selectedField.getFieldDefinition());
    String javaName = operation.map(op -> ((Member) op.getTypedElement().getElement()).getName()).orElse(null);
}
```

Be very careful though. If there's more than one Java element exposed per GraphQL field, `getTypedElement().getElement()` will explode. So to be sure you'd have to call `getTypedElement().getElements()` (plural) instead and decide what to do. `ClassUtils#getPropertyMembers` might also be useful, or the `ClassUtils.findXXX` family of methods.

You'd basically have to do this:

```
List<AnnotatedElement> elements = getTypedElement().getElements();
//Look for a field and use its name
Optional<String> field = Utils.extractInstances(elements, Field.class).findFirst().map(Field::getName);
//Look for a getter and find its associated field name
Optional<String> getter = Utils.extractInstances(elements, Method.class).findFirst().map(ClassUtils::getFieldNameFromGetter);
```

This API might have to change in future, as SDL-based tools are proliferating, so complex directives like the ones SPQR is using are causing problems...